# XSLT - How to use "value-of select=" when 2 xml tags share the same attribute name

Tags: xslt, csv

I am working on the following xml file:

```
<relational:BaseTable name="Table1">
    <columns name="Column1" Type="Number" </columns>
    <columns name="Column2" Type="Date" </columns>
 ....
```

I want create a CSV file like this

```
Table1, Column1, Number
Table1, Column1, Date
Table2, ...
```

I have figured out how to loop through the xml and format the output as csv. What the code below is missing is a way to repeat the name of the tables at the start of each line. I cannot figure out how to reference the "name" attribute of the parent (relational:BaseTable) tag.

```
<xsl:for-each select="relational:BaseTable">
   <xsl:for-each select="columns">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>,<xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks

Comment: I found this notation but doesn't seem to work <xsl:value-of select="/relational:BaseTable/@name" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the `BaseTable`'s `@name` attribute, you just need to move up the hiearchy a bit:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>,<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>,<xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
```

Note that you would need to do this even if the attribute names weren't the same, since the current reference context is a `columns` element.

I would also suggest simplifying the above line into a single `value-of`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(../@name, ',', @name, ',', @type)"/>
```